# CSS3 Cube with unordered list

Tags: html, css

I've seen many CSS3 Cube using div's, wanted to create the same with unordered list.

I managed to create the cube here http://codepen.io/iakshay/full/2/10. But I'm getting some extra margins between the faces.

Can't figure out whats going wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You used:

```
-webkit-transform: rotateX([X]deg) translateZ(200px);
```

When you use only `100px`  <del>I guess</del> it should work, like this:

```
-webkit-transform: rotateX([X]deg) translateZ(100px);
```

#### EDIT

Basically you have to use half the width because `rotateXYZ` rotates the element at a point in  the middle. When done you're already half the way and only have to add the "rest".

Here is a good example to see this effect on a mouseover:

http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/flip/

Comment: I'm guess now, it should be half the width of the cube. Why so?

Answer (score 1):

Your -webkit-transform: translateZ(200px); needs to be: -webkit-transform: translateZ(100px); on each side.  Took me a while the first time I ran through this as well :-)